# Do potions of decay generate in witch huts?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

According to the [Minecraft Wiki page for Swamp Huts](https://minecraft.wiki/Swamp_hut), potions of decay have a "rare chance" of being spawned inside cauldrons in swamp huts, but the exact chances as not specified. I have checked over 50 swamp huts using [the Witch Hut finder in Chunkbase.com](https://www.chunkbase.com/apps/witch-hut-finder) on my survival world, and none of them had a potion of decay.

In the history section of the wiki page it is said that in Pocket edition Alpha 0.16.0 Build one, potions of decay were added to the loot table, but the [page for the build itself](https://minecraft.wiki/Pocket_Edition_Alpha_0.16.0_build_1) did not include any information whatsoever on this matter.

So my question is, are potions of decay actually part of the loot table of potions that generate in swamp huts?

Answer (score 1):

Obtaining or creating a potion of decay in the vanilla build of the game isn't possible. Players will either need to access the potion or its variants in the Creative Mode inventory, console commands, or by using different third-party mods that allow decay potions to be created via the brewing stand and other methods

Console command = `/give @p potion 1 36`

Answer (score -1):

Yes, they do have a chance of spawning.

Comment: This answer would benefit from explanation. What are the chances of it spawning?

Answer (score -1):

I have done the research and you can get them. I spent ages trying to find the percentage chance because I am trying to get them myself, but I can't find it. I know that you can get them, but the chance, I believe since I found out the chances of getting other potions, is about 1.5%. That's not exact because there are more potion chances but I think that's it.